# How to uninstall Thrift

Tags: thrift

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 LTS machine on which I cloned the git repository of Thrift and built it locally from the source. But latest version has some changes in it's API which is causing out application's build procedure to fail.

Since the latest version of Thrift is tried is on my machine only, our team has decided to revert my system to an older and compatible version.

But I am finding it hard to uninstall the existing (latest) version. How shall I go about it?

Comment: this is a site for programming not software installing, should be on http://serverfault.com

Comment: @Jakub, Surely this site is for programmers and Thrift is a library (and not a software in conventional sense) used by programmers. I feel StackOverflow community is best suited to take this question.

Answer (score 10):

If you haven't deleted source tree from which you installed thrift by `./configure && make && sudo make install` then just `cd` to it and

```
sudo make uninstall
```

Otherwise:

```
git clone <repo>
git checkout <revision you installed>
./configure # if you supplied some additional options to configure while building thrift, add them here too.
sudo make uninstall
```

Answer (score 2):

To uninstall Thrift navigate to `tmp` as

```
$ cd /tmp
```

here you will find Thrift which you want to delete.

```
$ cd thrift-0.6.1
$ sudo make uninstall
$ cd ..
$ rm -rf thrift-0.6.1
```

This will uninstall Thrift.
For downloading other version you can use

```
$ curl http://apache.deathculture.net//thrift/0.6.1/thrift-0.6.1.tar.gz | tar zx
```