# Could not install thrift from ubuntu

Tags: thrift

I am new at  thrift communication , I  have successfully installed thrift version 0.9.1 but i need to install  thrift 0.9.3.1. i have installed both for testing but after removing  thrift version 0.9.3. 
The 'thrift -version' shows me thrift version 0.9.1. so thrift is still installed in my pc . i want to uninstall 0.9.1 bt  weird  thing is  i could not find the folder  of 0.9.1 version, we have searched for it  through code  but could not  find it .it will be great help if you clear my confusion. i could not find the folder yet. THank you

Answer (score -1):

To uninstall thrift uninstall it from /tmp folder:

$ cd /tmp

$ cd thrift-0.9.1

$ sudo make uninstall

$ cd ..

$ rm -rf thrift-0.9.1

Comment: thanks for your reply but  there is no folder in /tmp directory. any constructive suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: Can you share the commands using which you installed thrift? :)

Comment: Here's the right link: http://support.miritech.com/blog/how-to-install-configure-apache-thrift-in-ubuntu-16-04. A probably more autoritative source would be [the Ubuntu/Debian install instructions from the Apache Thrift homepage](https://thrift.apache.org/docs/install/debian), although the net essence is the same on both sites.

Comment: This answer should help you [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182403/how-to-uninstall-thrift]